# Logging with XQuery

Tags: spring-boot, xquery, logback, xquery-3.0

I'm using *XQuery 3.0* to transform an incoming message to fit my system.
The XQuery is called from an *Apache Camel* Route via the *transform* EIP.

Example:
`transform().xquery("resource:classpath:xquery/myxquery.xquery",String.class)`

While the transformation works without problems it would be nice, since it's partly very complex, to be able to log some informations directly during the transformation process.

**So I wanted to ask if it is possible to log "into" *logback* directly from *XQuery***?

I already searched stackoverflow and of course https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30-use-cases/ and other sources, but I just couldn't find any information about **how to log** in Xquery.

My project structure is:

- Spring-Boot 2 application
- Apache-Camel as Routing framework
- Logback as Logging framework

**Update**: For the integration of *XQuery* in the *Apache-Camel* Framework I use the `org.apache.camel:camel-saxon-starter:2.22.2`.

Comment: XQuery/XPath have a `trace` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-trace, you could try whether any output of it shows up in your log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Because the use of `fn:trace` was kind of ugly I searched further and now I use the extension mechanism from Saxon to provide different logging functions which can be accessed via xquery:

For more information see the documentation: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!extensibility/integratedfunctions/ext-full-J

Here is what I did for logging (tested with Saxon-HE, Camel is not mandatory, I just use it by coincidence):

#### First step:

Extend the class `net.sf.saxon.lib.ExtensionFunctionDefinition`

```
public class XQueryInfoLogFunctionDefinition extends ExtensionFunctionDefinition{

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XQueryInfoLogFunctionDefinition.class);

    private final XQueryInfoExtensionFunctionCall functionCall = new XQueryInfoExtensionFunctionCall();

    private static final String PREFIX = "log";

    @Override
    public StructuredQName getFunctionQName() {
        return new StructuredQName(PREFIX, "http://thehandofnod.com/saxon-extension", "info");
    }

    @Override
    public SequenceType[] getArgumentTypes() {
        return new SequenceType[] { SequenceType.SINGLE_STRING };
    }

    @Override
    public SequenceType getResultType(SequenceType[] suppliedArgumentTypes) {
        return SequenceType.VOID;
    }

    @Override
    public ExtensionFunctionCall makeCallExpression() {
        return functionCall;
    }

}
```

#### Second step:

Implement the FunctionCall class

```
public class XQueryInfoExtensionFunctionCall extends ExtensionFunctionCall {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XQueryInfoLogFunctionDefinition.class);

    @Override
    public Sequence call(XPathContext context, Sequence[] arguments) throws XPathException {
        if (arguments != null && arguments.length > 0) {
            log.info(((StringValue) arguments[0]).getStringValue());
        } else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("We need a message");
        return EmptySequence.getInstance();
    }
}
```

#### Third step:

Configure the SaxonConfiguration and bind it into the camel context:

```
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();

        Configuration saxonConfig = Configuration.newConfiguration(); 
        saxonConfig.registerExtensionFunction(new XQueryInfoLogFunctionDefinition());

        main.bind("saxonConfig", saxonConfig);
        main.addRouteBuilder(new MyRouteBuilder());
        main.run(args);
    }
```

#### Fourth step:

Define the SaxonConfig in your XQueryEndpoint:
`.to("xquery:test.xquery?configuration=#saxonConfig");`

#### Fifth step:

Call it in your xquery:

```
declare namespace log="http://thehandofnod.com/saxon-extension";
log:info("Das ist ein INFO test")
```

## Original post a.k.a How to overwrite the `fn:trace` Funktion:

Thanks to **Martin Honnen** I tried the `fn:trace` function. Problem was that by default it logs into the `System.err` Printstream and that's not what I wanted, because I wanted to combine the `fn:trace` function with the *Logback* Logging-Framework.

So I debugged the `net.sf.saxon.functions.Trace` methods and came to the following solution for my project setup.

1. Write a custom `TraceListener` which extends from `net.sf.saxon.trace.XQueryTraceListener` and implement the methods `enter` and `leave` in a way that the `InstructionInfo` with `constructType == 2041` (for *user-trace*) is forwarded to the SLF4J-API. Example (for only logging the message):

```
@Override
    public void enter(InstructionInfo info, XPathContext context) {
        // no call to super to keep it simple.
        String nachricht = (String) info.getProperty("label");
        if (info.getConstructType() == 2041 && StringUtils.hasText(nachricht)) {
            getLogger().info(nachricht);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void leave(InstructionInfo info) {
        // no call to super to keep it simple.
    }
```

2. set the custom trace listener into your `net.sf.saxon.Configuration` Bean via `setTraceListener`
3. Call your *xquery* file from camel via the `XQueryEndpoint` because only there it is possible to overwrite the `Configuration` with an option: `.to("xquery:/xquery/myxquery.xquery?configuration=#saxonConf")`. Unfortunately the `transform().xquery(...)` uses it's own objects without the possibility to configure them.
4. call `{fn:trace($element/text(),"Das ist ein Tracing Test")}` in your xquery and see the message in your log.